# :Save html as text

Tags: python, html, javascript

I have a javascript code which just show the source code of a html page

```
javascript:h=document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;function%20disp(h){h=h.replace(/</g,%20'\n&lt;');h=h.replace(/>/g,'&gt;');document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML='<pre>&lt;html&gt;'+h.replace(/(\n|\r)+/g,'\n')+'&lt;/html&gt;</pre>';}void(disp(h));
```

I save the code as a bookmark in firefox. So after loading a web page, when I select the code from the bookmark, and it shows the source code.

Now i try to save the html file using python.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
import BeautifulSoup

import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.doctorisin.net/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
print soup.prettify()
fp = open('file.txt','wb')
fp.write(soup.prettify())
```

But it does not have all the content that javascript code have. The saved file and the javascript shows source file is not same. Maybe python code does not get all the code(javascript/css tag code) from html page. What is the problem? Am i doing something wrong? Need help

thank you

**EDITED**

As an example of my problem, **http://phpjunkyard.com/tutorials/cut-paste-code.php** (random site ) Go to this site, right click and select view page source(firefox) copy the source and save in a text file. Now save the page (save page as). You can see that both are not same. Saved page(save as) has something more. Python give the output like source code(view page source). It is missing some scripts, forms etc.

Comment: This looks like a BeautifulSoup question, not an Ubuntu question. You are not simply trying to save the source as text, you are using some code to modify the source before you save it. If you want to save the source, try the right-click menu from your browser of choice and you should be able to save it rather easily.

Comment: Why do you expect BeautifulSoup to render JavaScript?

Comment: Also why do you have so redundant imports in your code snippet?

Comment: @Wolfger I need to save a html page for my project. So i need to use code.

Comment: @zetah I did not mention this. I just want to say that the txt file generated by python is not same as the firefox (save page as) generate. what is the problem? And redundant imports does not harm. and sorry for redundancy. thanks all for reply.

Comment: You don't need BeautifulSoup to save html page as text (as in Firefox - save page as). Just use `page.read()`, for your example snippet. BeautifulSoup is parser for HTML/XML - it allows you to manipulate HTML data

Comment: i have already done this. As an example of my problem, http://www.phpjunkyard.com/tutorials/cut-paste-code.php Go to this site, right click and select view page source(firefox) copy the source and save in a text file. Now save the page (save page as). You can see that both are not same. Saved page(save as) has something more. Python give the output like source code(view page source). It is missing some scripts, forms etc.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to save the exact HTML that the web server gives, don't use `BeautifulSoup` (which is an HTML parser and will likely modify the code when prettyprinting it back); this would be a better solution:

```
import urllib2
file("my_file.txt", "w").write(urllib2.urlopen("http://www.doctorisin.net/").read())
```

Firefox by default saves not only the HTML but also files that are needed to display the page (including css and scripts).

Comment: thank you. I have already tried this. Please see the edited post. I have described my problem with an example.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is the difference between static and dynamic webpages.

Unlike static webpages, dynamic webpages can modify the underlying html as they loading. Javascript can dump the full html of the loaded page, because it has access to the modified DOM created by the browser.

In contrast, if the same webpage is downloaded from the server and fed directly to `BeautifulSoup`, it will only be able to parse it as static html. To get the full, dynamic content, the page would need to be processed by a browser (or the equivalent) first.